# JS returning value not the same in function as returning it from outside of it

Tags: javascript

first post here! Trying to fix this and looking for an answer online but not luck -I know its out there, but cant seem to figure it out- I have a javascript code to return the location of the user as follows:

```
var myLatlon = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

And the function is as follows:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    var latlon=position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude;
    return latlon;
};
```

When I do a console.log(latlon); inside the function above it returns the actual latitude and longitude separated by a comma.

But when I do a console.log(myLatlon) after the first line; it returns: **{"timer":true}**

I need to return from my function the actual latitude and longitude. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return the value from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. That's the nature of asynchronous calls. The call to  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` finishes way before the callback is called. You have to use your coordinates within your `onSuccess` callback

Usually restructuring your code has almost the same effect as returning it.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    // Use position from here
}, onError);
// This line is reached before the commented line in the anonymous function above, that's why you can't return the value
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you simply cannot return from a callback used for handling asynchronous execution. Any code that depends on the value you'd *like* to return must be called in the callback.

That's simply how async works.